# Symmetric matrices written as $X^T X$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

Can we prove that if some matrix $A$ is symmetric, then we are able to write it in the form $A = X^T X$?

Comment: If $A$ is real and symmetric, and if $X$ is real, then the answer is "no". This is because the eigenvalues of $A$ could be negative, but the eigenvalues of $X^{T}X$ cannot be.

Comment: Consider $[-1]$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

No; since we have $\langle v, X^T X v \rangle = \langle Xv, Xv \rangle \ge 0$, a matrix of the form $X^T X$ is always positive semidefinite, so always has non-negative eigenvalues. So any symmetric matrix with a negative eigenvalue cannot be written in this way.

This is the only obstruction; every positive semidefinite symmetric matrix $A$ can be written $X^T X$ for some $X$. This follows from the spectral theorem: $A$ can be written $UDU^{-1}$ where $U$ is an orthogonal matrix (whose columns are an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $A$) and $D$ is a diagonal matrix with non-negative entries (the non-negative eigenvalues of $A$). Now take $X = \sqrt{D} U^{-1} = \sqrt{D} U^T$, where $\sqrt{D}$ means taking the componentwise square root.

Comment: Of course $X^T$ is the adjoint with respect to a positive definite form. If one chooses an indefinite (nondegenerate) from I imagine you can represent symmetric matrices of the same signature.